# Is there a JTreeTable implementation that allows variable row height

Tags: java, swing, swingx, treetable, jtreetable

I have been searching for a little while on this one.  I need a `JTreeTable` that supports variable row height.  Specifically, **I want the rows that show the top level nodes to be taller than the child rows beneath them.**

I have been using the SwingX implementation (`JXTreeTable`) which is based on the [original Sun articles](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/).  However, it specifically disallows variable row height, and without rewriting `JXTree` I can't see a way through.

Any tips / pointers would be gratefully received before I embark on something nasty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans has the Outline component which is a tree table, and it can be used outside NetBeans (just find the right JAR files).
Here is an article about it:
http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-

I may be wrong but I believe it supports variable row heights.

Comment: +1 Have started to look at this - you're right in that you do get variable row heights.  Still trying to figure out if the rest of it is mature enough for me.